# Azure table set query

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to implement a structure like the following: with property name "u:uid ", so that I can do a query like [(u:112 eq 1) or  (u:118 eq 1)  or  (u:119 eq 1)] . It can potentially get the work done, just that I fear it would not be good for situation like searching for hundreds of uid. And when the application grows the number of "columns" can grow to tens of thousand. Can anyone familiar with the azure table architecture shed some light on this? And would there be alternative way to implement the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

So a few things here:

- You can't name your attribute with a `:` in it.
- Assuming `u` is an attribute name in the table, querying just on it would result in full table scan as your query does not include `PartitionKey`. While this may not be an issue if your table is small however it would create a lot of problems as your table grow big.

If the `uid` is unique, I suggest you set its value as the PartitionKey and then you could query like

```
(PartitionKey eq '112') or (PartitionKey eq '118') or (PartitionKey eq '119')
```

I would strongly recommend reading this blog post from Windows Azure Storage team before proceeding: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick reply. Unfortunately in my case I had already used other properties as PartitionKey and RowKey. Do you think  having thousands of keys("columns") like (u11, u133, u134 ......) a problem?

Comment: There's a limit of 256 keys (attributes --> columns) per entity so you can't have 1000s of these keys in just one entity. Secondly, make sure you use `PartitionKey` in your query at all times. Omitting it from your query **will definitely have negative impact**. Can you update your question with complete data structure you're planning on using? That would certainly help in providing you with a meaningful answer.

Comment: The 256 keys limit do render my approach impossible. So in essence I have to do query like uid IN(1,33,2333,2888,33322). Since the Partitionkey is otherwise occupied  I have to try using property-value to achieve this.

Comment: Please note that `IN` is also not supported. You would have to do `or` query like in your question.